# TypeError:Super expression must either be null or a function

Tags: react-native

getting error while making the below page, give me solution for this!!

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import { Text,View ,StyleSheet, TextInput, Button} from 'react-native';

import ValidationComponent from '../index';

export default class Register extends ValidationComponent {

constructor(props) {

super(props);

 this.state = {First_name : "First Name",Last_name : 'Last Name', email: "tibtib@gmail.com", password:"****", confirm_password : '****' };

  }
```

Comment: I suspect this is do with `ValidationComponent`. What is that? You probably want to extend `Component`, which you're importing in line 1.

Comment: I was trying to validate my form, by including validationcomponent library!!

Comment: Do you get the error if you change `ValidationComponent` to `Component`? I have a feeling this library will cause you more trouble than it's worth, and you could do any form validation you need yourself quite easily, I would think.

Comment: Yes, I'm getting the error when I changed it to Component. Yeah I'm also thinking to leave it

Comment: Would you mind posting the code for the entire component, please? I don't see anything else in the current code that should cause it to break...

Comment: I just deleted the validationcomponent library and my code look like this, can you help me with this...

Comment: <View style={styles.borderS}>
           <TextInput ref='First_Name'
                onChangeText={(value) => this._onPressButton(value, 'firstname')}
                value={this.state.First_Name}
           />
       </View>

Comment: _onPressButton(val, type) {
     var textvalue = Target.value
    console.log('value =>', textvalue)
    switch(textvalue){
      case (type === 'firstname'):
        if(textvalue.length >= 4 ){
          this.setState({firstname_val: true})
        }

Comment: Its kinda messy but you can understand, I'm getting reference error: Cant find variable: Target

Comment: Ok I think I've figured out what you're trying to do haha. Also for future reference you can edit your post, you don't have to use comments xD. See my answer below :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you've just become a bit confused about passing the variables around. As per our convo in the comments, here's my attempt at what I think you're trying to do (with explanations):

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import { Text, View, StyleSheet, TextInput } from 'react-native';

export default class Register extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      firstName: { // I have split this so you can store the value and a valid flag conveniently
        value: '', // removed initial value and used a placeholder in the element instead
        isValid: false
      },
      lastName: '',
      email: 'tibtib@gmail.com',
      password: '****',
      confirmPassword: '****'
    };
  }

  checkIfValid = (type, value) => { // you can add more checks to this as you add more fields
    if (type == 'firstName') return value.length >= 4;
  }

  _onChangeText = (type, value) => {
    // console.log('value =>', value);
    const isValid = this.checkIfValid(type, value) // check validity whenever new text is entered

    this.setState({ // removed the switch statement and just setState with the isValid variable above
      [type]: {
        value,
        isValid
      }
    })
  };

  firstInputStyle = () => { // so we can change the style dynamically depending on state
    if (!this.state.firstName.isValid) return styles.firstNameTextInput;

    return [styles.firstNameTextInput, styles.isValid]; // if valid, add the isValid style
    // you could also generalise this method to work on all input fields
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <TextInput
          style={this.firstInputStyle()} // here we get the style dynamically with the method above
          onChangeText={value => this._onChangeText('firstName', value)}
          value={this.state.firstName.value} // need to tie the value to our state
          placeholder='Enter first name...'
        />
        <Text>First name valid = {this.state.firstName.isValid.toString()}</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({ // some dummy styles I made up
  container: {
    padding: 20,
    paddingTop: 30,
    height: '100%'
  },
  firstNameTextInput: {
    borderColor: 'black',
    borderWidth: 1,
    fontSize: 25,
    padding: 10
  },
  isValid: {
    backgroundColor: 'green'
  }
});
```

I hope that make sense... let me know if you have questions!

Note: I've also updated some of your variable names to camelCase as this is more conventional

Comment: I made changes according to your explanation but its not enough, I still can't get my form validated as the Constructor I'm passing can't get deleted manually from my application page.

Comment: There were some things I missed. I played around with it and fixed it to a basic working example of what I think you're trying to do. You can view it here. I added comments in the code, and I'll update the answer here as well. Here you go: https://snack.expo.io/B1bX7Ei1U